# A op B = 0, with neither A nor B zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Are there some well known mathematical objects with one or more associated binary operators such that two such objects $A$ and $B$ when combined with an operator yield $0$, although neither $A$ nor $B$ is $0$? Not interested in XOR or discrete math types of things, more where $A$ and $B$ might act as coefficients and have a norm of some kind.

Apologies if this is painfully obvious to this community, but I'll appreciate a pointer in the right direction (or an explanation for why such objects could not exist). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure there's a clear distinction between "discrete math types of things" and whatever it is you want.

Comment: $1-1=0$ might be an example

Comment: Fair enough, I know that phrase is kind of mushy, just wanted to head off 1 XOR 1.

Comment: Maybe you mean "associative", rather than "associated".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  any ring that is not a domain has such things, they are called "zero divisors".  A classic example is square matrices $n\times n$ with any size greater than $n=1
$

As an example,  let $A=B=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

Then $A^2=0$.

Comment: Thanks Alan, this is along the lines I was hoping for!

Comment: @CHC No problem. If this answered your question, go ahead and click the check mark to accept the answer.  Welcome to MSE!

Comment: The ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field, but it still contains no zero divisors. So, you should replace "field" with "domain".

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang Thanks, fixed.  Been like 6 years or so since I actually did these,  forgot my list of UFD/Domain/Ring/Field/Etc. hierarchy :)

Comment: Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

First, elements with your property are called [zero divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_divisor).

For $0$ to even make sense, you want at the *very* least a monoid, and then another operation on the set to make the zero divisors; i.e. a ring-like structure $(R,+,\cdot)$. The vast majority of usual examples you see will be rings.

A ring without zero divisors is called an integral domain, so take a look at the list of non-examples on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_domain#Non-examples) on integral domains. The most familiar examples are probably

- $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, i.e. the ring of integers modulo $n$, where $n$ is composite,
- Matrix rings,
- Rings of functions (even continuous/smooth/...).

For examples of non-rings with zero-divisors, you can dive into [this wiki rabbit hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure).

(In a Boolean ring, all elements other than $0$ and $1$ are zero divisors (since $x^2=x\implies x(x-1)=0$) – but the usual Boolean ring is the one with symmetric difference.)